# Is it possible to access declared types from java when using the ruleunit api?

Tags: rules, rule-engine, fact

in the legacy java drool "API" it was possible to gain access to the types declared within the rule files via the KieBase.getFactType(...) method. Is such thing possible with the new RuleUnit based API? If yes, how?

Thanks,
Alex

I am trying to gain access to the declared types, to be able to provide the appropriate facts from java (dynamically from maps), when these types are declared in the rules.